# Stacking Matrix Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, matrix-equations

Suppose $\mathbf x_1,\mathbf x_2,\mathbf y_1,\mathbf y_2$ are $1 \times n$ vectors and $\mathbf A_1,\mathbf A_2$ are $n \times n$ matrices and consider the system
\begin{align}
\mathbf x_1 =&\;\; \omega_1\mathbf x_2 \mathbf A_1 + (1-\omega_1)\mathbf y_1\\[2ex]
\mathbf x_2 =&\;\; \omega_2\mathbf x_1 \mathbf A_2 + (1-\omega_2)\mathbf y_2.
\end{align}
where $\omega_1,\omega_2$ are scalars. Is it possible to stack these equations to solve for 
$$ \mathbf X = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf x_1 \\ \mathbf x_2 \end{bmatrix}?$$

Comment: Why do you want to stack them? stacking is usually done when a variable appears in more than one equation.

Comment: @Med Oh, I apologize, I have a typo. I will fix it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?
$$\begin{bmatrix} I_n &-\omega_1 A_1 \\ -\omega_2 A_2 & I_n \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} (1-\omega_1)y_1 \\ (1-\omega_2)y_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} (1-\omega_1)I_n & 0 \\ 0 & (1-\omega_2)I_n \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}y_1\\ y_2\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks. I think you have transposed everything, right?

Comment: @mzp No, I just had a typo ($A_2$ instead of $A_1$).

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but the A matrices are post multiplying the vectors in the question and premultiplying them in you answer. I think it works out if you transpose everything in the question.

Comment: @mzp Oh I see, I hadn't noticed they where row vectors. If you understood the answer you'll manage to correct it accordingly (either using transpose, or changing the order).